# Office VSTO Word 2003 project keeps trying to autoconvert to 2007

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, vsto

I am working on a Office Word add-in for Word 2003. When I reopen the project, the VS2008 auto covert dialog box opens and tries to convert it to the Word 2007 format.

How can I reopen this file and keep it in the Word 2003 format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a answer over at [MSDN Forums](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3764492&SiteID=1)

> This is the default behavior when you have Office 2007 installed on your
>   development computer. You can modify
>   this behavior under Tools->Options.
>   For more informaiton, see the
>   following threads:
>
> http://forums.microsoft.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3762143&SiteID=1
>
> http://forums.microsoft.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3742203&SiteID=1&mode=1
>
> I hope this helps,
>
> McLean Schofield

Comment: Do you remember any details of what needs fixed?  Both of the URLs in your quoted material are 404.